# simple powershell variable not being stored for use later in script

Tags: powershell, variables, scope

I am new to powershell and trying to build a simple script. While I am able to set a variable with the read-host command, it does return results when called.

If I substitute an actual city name the script instead of the varialbe it works as intended so I must be missing something with scope?

```
$location = Read-Host -Prompt "enter the city name"
#get a list of users who have mailboxes in a specific city
$cityusers = Get-User -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {(RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (City -eq $location)}
```

I expect the script to return results based on the city input in the read-host command, but instead I get users from multiple cities. If I specify the city by name (no variable) it works as expected.

Comment: [Variable Substitution in a PowerShell Script Block](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/variable-substitution-in-a-powershell-script-block/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally have this working now. The problem was with the way I was trying to filter mailboxes by type and city:

```
-User -ResultSize unlimited -Filter {(RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (City -eq $location)}
```

This needs to be done instead with $_ variables like this:

```
#prompt for a city
$location = Read-Host -Prompt "enter the city"

#get a list of users who have mailboxes in a specific city
$cityusers = Get-User -ResultSize unlimited | Where-Object {($_.RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'UserMailbox') -and ($_.city -eq $location)}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Took me a minute, but I think I found your error. Keep in mind that variables don't actually execute as commands, but only when called. I.E

```sh
$dont_execute = 10+20
echo "Only this line shows."
```

while this does:

```sh
$execute = 10+20
echo $execute
#Should show 30
echo "Oh hey, now you have two lines, but only because you used the variable."
```

Notice how I use the variable instead of letting it sit there. Make sure you script isn't doing the same.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but I haven't been able to figure out how to adjust my script to make the variable "active". I've tried invoke-expression but that doesn't seem to work either. Perhaps I need to rewrite it altogether.

Comment: Well how about this. Post a section of the script that you are having trouble with (Make sure you take out sensitive info), and I'll modify it so you can understand.

Comment: So I tried to create an example that didn't depend on O365 to make testing easier and it is actually working  

`$a = Read-Host -Prompt "Type the service name e.g. WinRM"`
`$b = Get-Service | Where-Object {($_.Status -eq "Running") -and ($_.ServiceName -eq $a)}`  
`$b`  

Perhaps the `-filter` in the original codeblock is the problem?